# How to Format this Date "2018-08-02T00:00:00+05:30" String to this "2018-18-02"

Tags: java, date

```
public class Kf_Date {

    public static String getDateUsingOracleFormat(String date) {
        try {
            DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");
            Date date2 = inputFormat.parse(date);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYY-MM-dd");
            String outputText = sdf.format(date2);
            return outputText;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(new Kf_Date().getDateUsingOracleFormat("2018-08-02T00:00:00+05:30"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Code as text, not images please

Comment: Those represent different days ... "_2018-08-02T00:00:00+05:30_” <> “_2018-18-02_” so even if you go crazy and just substring the first 10 character, it won't be the same date. But FYI : **S** is for millisecond. You want **X** for timezone ! Like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`

Comment: What is the transformation rule? Subtract 5 1/2 hours and add 10 days?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
   .format(ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-08-02T00:00:00+05:30"))
```

That returns `"2018-08-02"`. The `parse` call above understands the ISO format of your input.

That's newer and recommended API. If you're using Java older than 8, you should use:

```
Date input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
                 .parse("2018-08-02T00:00:00+05:30");
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                 .format(input);
```

And this returns the same string.

Comment: First half of this Answer is correct. But the suggestion to use the terrible `SimpleDateFormat` & `Date` classes is ill-advised. Instead, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* library that brings most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & Java 7. Further adapted to earlier Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` would be a still better and more precise choice than `ZonedDateTime` since the string has an offset in it and no time zone. The rest of the code could be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You have correct code except this line. Use **XXX** instead of **.S** in the input pattern:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

According to [Class SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/):

- **X** - Time zone,  ISO 8601 time zone *(-08; -0080; -08:-00)*
- **S** - Millisecond, Number *(978)*

**Hint:**

In case you have problem with parse date string and do not know what is wrong in your patter, then just print current date and compare it with your input string. Then you can see the difference and fix the pattern:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");
System.out.println(inputFormat.format(new Date())); // 2018-08-07T08:28:33.800

inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
System.out.println(inputFormat.format(new Date())); // 2018-08-07T08:28:33+03:00
```

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

```
public static String getDateUsingOracleFormat(String date) {
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
    String outputText = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    return outputText;
}
```

With this method declaration your `main` prints:

> 2018-08-02

Both your formats (the one you are parsing and the one you are producing) conform with ISO 8601 (link at the bottom). The classes of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, parse and print this format as their default, that is, with out any explicit formatter. Also the formatters are built in, so I am using one for specifying that we want the date formatted without the time of day and the offset from UTC. No need for the error-prone task of writing your own formatters.

### What went wrong in your code?

As others have said, your format pattern string does not match the date-time string you are trying to parse 100 %. The format requires that after that seconds there should be a dot and some milliseconds. Instead you string has an offset, `+05:30`. This causes the exception. By contrast the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse` accepts strings with and without milliseconds (since they are optional in ISO 8601) (but does require the offset).

There’s one more bug in your code: the use of uppercase `YYY` in the format pattern you are formatting to. This will occasionally give you the wrong year. Lowercase `y` is for year of era. Uppercase `Y` is for week year and only useful with a week number.

As an aside, since your method is static, you don’t need to create an instance to call it. Just do:

```
    System.out.println(Kf_Date.getDateUsingOracleFormat("2018-08-02T00:00:00+05:30"));
```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: This is the best Answer. (A) It avoids using the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes, and (B) it uses `OffsetDateTime` class which is more appropriate than the `ZonedDateTime` class seen in another Answer. An offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours, minutes, and seconds. We see this in the input used in Question, `+05:30`. A time zone is much more, a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. Zones have `Continent/Region` names such as `Asia/Kolkata` or `Europe/Paris`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ISO pattern like this:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTimeUtils {

    public static String format(String inputDate, String inputFormat, String outputFormat) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);
        fromFormat.setLenient(false);
        DateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat);
        toFormat.setLenient(false);
        Date date = fromFormat.parse(inputDate);
        return toFormat.format(date);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(DateTimeUtils.format("2018-08-02T00:00:00+05:30", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find available timeZone using this method

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs());
```

after finding you want timeZone use the below code

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Argentina/San_Luis"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Please do not confirm to the young ones that we may use the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. We have so much better in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Which issue were you having with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51741129/5772882)? I tried it myself and it worked for me.

Comment: It seems you are solving a different problem from the one asked about. I think you want `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/San_Luis")).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)`. It just gave `2023-03-15T05:33:51-03:00`, which is the same output I get from your code. Available time zone IDs come from `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.